# Что в данном случаи лучше использовать: Асинхронное или Параллельное программирование?

Tags: c#

Задача простая, но столкнулся с проблемой слишком долгого выполнения (30+ минут)
Суть задачи пройти по большому кол-ву элементов (60000) в коллеции (List) и с каждым элементом сделать определенное действие (в данном случаи элемент загружается в библиотеку, которая с ним что-то делает)

Вот мой код

```
for (int i = 0; i < uniqueUserAgents.Count; i++)
{
    var res = Result(uniqueUserAgents[i]);
    dictionaryUserAgents.Add(uniqueUserAgents[i], res.Result);
    Console.WriteLine($"Выполнено {i} из {uniqueUserAgents.Count}");
}

// uniqueUserAgents - кол-во элментов (60000)

public static async Task<Dictionary<string, IAgentField>> Result(string userAgent)
{
    var ua_new = ParsingUserAgentInNewLibraryAsync(userAgent);
    await Task.WhenAll(ua_new);
    return ua_new.Result;
}

public static async Task<Dictionary<string, IAgentField>> ParsingUserAgentInNewLibraryAsync(string userAgent)
{
    var immutableUserAgent = // тут подключение к библиотеки
    var fieldNames = // тут получение информации из библиотеки

    Dictionary<string, IAgentField> fields = new Dictionary<string, IAgentField>();
    foreach (var name in fieldNames)
    {
       fields[name] = immutableUserAgent.Get(name);
    }

    await Task.CompletedTask;

    return fields;
}
```

Вот, получается, что данный код выполняется слишком долго, поможет ли в данном случаи параллельность? Если нет, то как что Вы могли бы посоветовать для ускорения работы кода?

Comment: Задача заключается в том, что над каждым элементом из коллекции надо проезвести определенные дейтсвия в библиотеке

Comment: А библиотека то умеет в асинхронность? Вы при обращении к библиотеке не используете асинхронный вызов. Ещё вопрос в том, что происходит, если к библиотеке обращаются во много потоков сразу. Хорошо ли библиотека на это реагирует? А то может она только один запрос одновременно обрабатывать умеет. Без этих знаний без толку что-то проектировать.

Comment: Если скорость работы библиотеки непонятно от чего зависит, она сама лазит куда-то в БД или ещё куда-то, то это IO bound задача и нужно использовать асинхронность (и хорошо бы библиотека имела асинхронный интерфейс). А если работа библиотеки довольно равномерная - она просто молотит какие-то данные с более-менее предсказуемой одинаковой скоростью - то это уже CPU bound задача и можно использовать многопоточность. Повторюсь - при условии, что обращение к библиотеке хорошо масштабируется и параллельные вызовы библиотеки не замедляют её работу настолько, что лучше к ней параллельно не обращаться.

Comment: @CrazyElf Сама библиотека не имеет асинхронности, но она прекрасно работает с несколькми потоками

Comment: Ну, тогда я всё написал выше. В общем случае можете использовать любой подход, хотя в последнее время больше используется асинхронность, чем многопоточность, она более универсальна.